# is there a way to solve " Kubeconfig user entry is using deprecated API version client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1 " with pulumi

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, pulumi

I get the following error message whenever I run a pulumi command. I verified and my kubeconfig file is `apiVersion: v1` I updated `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1` to `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1` and still have the issue, what could be the reason for this error message?

```
Kubeconfig user entry is using deprecated API version client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1. Run 'aws eks update-kubeconfig' to update.
```

Comment: did you try to `delete` it and `create` it with a `yaml` config file that respect the `apiVersion: v1` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bug report for this issue is [here](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-eks/issues/599)

The underlying cause is that the AWS cli shipped a breaking change in a minor version release. You can see this [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6920)

I'm assuming here you're using the `pulumi-eks` package in order to provision an EKS cluster greater than `v1.22`. The EKS package uses a resource provider to configure some EKS resources like the `aws-auth` config map, and this isn't the same transient kubeconfig you're referring to in `~/.kube/config`

In order to fix this, you need to do the following:

- Ensure your `aws-cli` version is greater than `1.24.0` or `2.7.0`
- Ensure you've updated your `pulumi-eks` package in your language SDK package manager to greater than `0.40.0`. This will mean also updated the provider in your existing stack.
- Ensure you have the version of `kubectl` installed locally that matches your cluster version that has been provisioned

Comment: Great, am using pulumi with typescript, I upgraded @pulumi/eks to 0.40.0 and @pulumi/aws to 5.6.0, aws cli to 2.7.5. and everything worked. thank you

Comment: I upgraded @pulumi/aws to 5.7.4, but was instantly greeted with the error "unable to discover AWS AccessKeyID and/or SecretAccessKey", though I've all credentials in ~/.aws/credentials.

Comment: @samox thats a different error, please open a new question